# Loop through number array to construct object of index nodes

Tags: javascript

I have an array such as [2,5,3,1] each number represents an index number. How would I be able to construct an object path using these nodes? For example:

[2,5] would create:

```
myObject.conversations[i].conversations[i]
```

[2,5,3,1] would create:

```
myObject.conversations[i].conversations[i].conversations[i].conversations[i]
```

I can only use basic javascript. I tried a for loop to construct a string which I could just keep adding to but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like homework.

```js
var source = [,,,[,,[,,,,[,,,'foo']]]];
console.log(source[3][2][4][3]);

console.log([3, 2, 4, 3].reduce((o, i) => o[i], source));
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce` is for sure the right approach.

Comment: Cool thanks. I forgot to mention of course that ‘conversations’ is an array, would your answer still work?

Comment: This answer is easily extensible. `(o, i) => o.conversations[i]`

Answer (score 1):

```
  function minimizeElems(keyArray,object){
    var obj = object;
    for(keys of keyArray){
      obj = obj[keys];
    }
    return obj;
  }
```

Hope this function helps.

Comment: Cool thanks. I forgot to mention of course that ‘conversations’ is an array, would your answer still work?

Comment: if you want to get the value of a key, from your object like, obj.key1.key2 and key1 and key2 are the elements of your conversations array, it should work